# try...catch needed in async call inside useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, async-await, try-catch

I'm trying to do some async stuff in a `useEffect` hook. So first I define the async function and second I'm calling that function.
I am not quite sure how to handle errors correctly. Is the `try...catch` part also needed as the `.catch` of the function call? Isn't it the same?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth.token')
      // do something
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }

  fetchData().catch(console.error)
}, [])
```

Comment: The outer .catch is pointless because the inner async catch turns any rejection into an undefined resolution. This is unrelated to React/useEffect, just basic promise use.

Comment: *"Isn't it the same?"*: quite often there are many ways to reach the same goal.

Comment: The try...catch block inside the function is used to handle errors that occur within the scope of that function and the catch block at the end of the function call is used to handle any errors that occur while trying to call the function, such as a network error.

Comment: You're correct. You don't need both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to handle asynchronous operations in JavaScript, you can use `async` `await` or `.then()` & `.catch()`. Here is an example of both:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth.token')
      // do something
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    }
  }

  fetchData()
}, [])
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('auth.token')
      .then(token => console.log(token))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }
  fetchData()
}, [])
```